# MY canon D1200 doesn't take a picture in AF mode

Tags: canon

So my new canon d1200 doesn't take pictures in AF mode , my both lenses(50mm and 18-55mm)
I have tried searching but up till now there is no solution. My canon takes picture in manual mode but in auto focus mode the lenses rotate (to focus) but don't take a picture it shows busy and no picture is taken but when i take the picture in auto focus, live mode (seeing through the screen) the picture is taken. i don't understand what the problem is . i have tried cleaning the lenses , still no use. ya, when i take pictures of tube lights , the pictures are taken .

Comment: Canon does not have a D1200 model that I am aware of so I'm assuming you are speaking of the 1200D/T5 model. If the camera is unable to take a picture, are you sure that you are in a situation with enough light and contrast to successfully obtain autofocus lock? What conditions are you shooting in? Try outdoors in bright light. What mode is the camera mode dial in? Green square(auto)? Something else? What do you mean by "when i take pictures of tube lights, the pictures are taken"? What is a tube light?

Answer (score 2):

The camera will not take a picture if the lens does not have focus lock.

When you put it in manual focus, the camera will take photos whether there is focus lock or not.

In live mode the camera will take a photo even if not in focus, because autofocus does not operate in live view mode, since the autofocus detector is no longer in the light path. This is because the autofocus detector is up in the viewfinder prism box area, and it requires the mirror to be down and active. Newer cameras (7DMkII, 70D, etc) have some ability to autofocus with the sensor itself.

If you can no get focus lock with either lens, then there may be an issue with the electrical contacts on your camera (where the lens attaches) or a problem with the autofocus detector. Try cleaning the contacts with a pencil eraser.

Comment: The camera will take a photo if it's in AI Servo mode even without a confirmed focus lock (at least, the 550D will).

Comment: @PhilipKendall Some Canon bodies allow the user to select whether the shutter will or will not release without confirming focus first. With them the camera may or may not take a photo in AI Servo mode without a confirmed focus lock, depending on the selected option in the custom functions.

Comment: @cmason In Live view the camera uses contrast detection AF because as you point out, the phase detection AF hardware is no longer in the light path. Some newer models also include a hybrid PDAF in the design of the sensor. But all Canon cameras with a Live View mode will autofocus in Live View mode using contrast detection.

Comment: @MichaelClark Not all Canon cameras with Live View: my 40D does not focus in live view

Comment: OK, all Canon cameras with Live View except the 40D, the 1D Mark III, and the 1Ds Mark III (the first Canon cameras to incorporate Live View).